# How to stop the voice during text-to-speech synthesis?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, text-to-speech

I used the following code to initial the text to speech synthesis using a button. But sometimes users may want to stop the voice in the middle of the speech. May i know is there any code i can do that.

Thanks

Here is my code

```
@interface RMDemoStepViewController ()

@end

@implementation RMDemoStepViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Add Border to TextBox


    //Instantiate the object that will allow us to use text to speech
    self.speechSynthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
    [self.speechSynthesizer setDelegate:self];

}
- (IBAction)speakButtonWasPressed:(id)sender{

    [self speakText:[self.textView text]];

}

- (void)speakText:(NSString *)toBeSpoken{

    AVSpeechUtterance *utt = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:toBeSpoken];
    utt.rate = [self.speedSlider value];
    [self.speechSynthesizer speakUtterance:utt];

}

- (IBAction)speechSpeedShouldChange:(id)sender
{
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
    NSInteger val = lround(slider.value);
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)val]);
}
@end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But sometimes users may want to stop the voice in the middle of the speech.

To stop speech, send the speech synthesizer a [`-stopSpeakingAtBoundary:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechSynthesizer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVSpeechSynthesizer/stopSpeakingAtBoundary%3a) message:

```
[self.speechSynthesizer stopSpeakingAtBoundary:AVSpeechBoundaryImmediate];
```

Use `AVSpeechBoundaryWord` instead of `AVSpeechBoundaryImmediate` if you want the speech to continue to the end of the current word rather than stopping instantly.

You can also [pause speech](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechSynthesizer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVSpeechSynthesizer/pauseSpeakingAtBoundary%3a) instead of stopping it altogether.

Answer (score -1):

This will completely stop the SpeechSynthesizer: `-stopSpeakingAtBoundary` and if you want more code after the SS, then put `:` at the end of that. So basically, `-stopSpeakingAtBoundary:` For the full code to fit in with yours, here: `[self.speechSynthesizer stopSpeakingAtBoundary:AVSpeechBoundaryImmediate];`